# Pip 1.5 and git dependency set in setup.py do not work together

Tags: python, git, pip

I have an issue with the latest pip. 
My problem is the following:

- I have a python project with a setup.py defining its dependencies.
- One of them is a custom jenkins-job-builder that I would like to install from a custom Git repository, hosted on Stash.
- It worked fine with older pip, but with pip 1.5 security improvement, I cannot find a way to install everything correctly. My exact version of pip is 1.5.4.

To be more concrete:

In my setup.py I have:

```
install_requires = [
        #... stuff
        'compcomp==0.8.2beta',],
  dependency_links= [
        # depends on Hotel jobs builder to have Hg support !
        'git+http://<blablalba>/compcomp.git#egg=compcomp-0.8.2beta'
    ],
```

I try to run the following commands at the root of my project (from a freshly created virtualenv).

- If I run "pip install -e .", I get: ... Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow)... .
- If I try "pip install --allow-external compcomp -e .", I get the exact (!) same error.
- If I try "pip install --allow-all-external -e . ", I get: ... Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified compcomp to allow).
- And if I try "pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified compcomp -e .", I get the same previous error.

I am not sure I understand what is happening here, it seems I am not able to target the dependency defined in my setup.py :S.

Anyone has an idea on what could go wrong ? I googled for a while and did not find any clue .

EDIT:

I am debugging pip code to understand what is going wrong, and it looks like the warning I get from pip is not the correct one.

Some other dependency (mox to be accurate, which gets downloaded at the end) is settings pip attribute "need_warn_unverified" to True, but then the warning message I get "Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified compcomp to allow)" talks about my component.

I guess this is a bug in pip, but I still do not understand why my dependency is never found.

Comment: How is it that your dependencies have the same name as your package?

Comment: I guess I am missing something :-). The dependency declared in my setup.py and the package name should not be necessarily the same ?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I found the issue which has nothing to do with the warnings I got from pip. I simply have to add `--process-dependency-links` to my call to `pip install`. So I guess there is a simple misleading info got from pip when it cannot find a dependency and a warning has been raised by another dependency.